# Read permission denied even when using sudo and all permissions are granted

Tags: permissions

I have this virus that came from an npm package and I want to read the code. My problem is that I cannot read the contents of the file.

Trying to make it readable, I took the drastic step of allowing all permissions on the file.  (Yes, I know.  Kids, don't play with matches or set random things to 777.) I `chmod`ed it to 777 and moved it to my Desktop. I'm the owner of the file. I changed the extension to `.txt`, and its icon is now a bunch of characters.

I've tried `sudo cat` as well.  No, I'm not about to execute it as the superuser or anything like that.  I thought that the superuser would bypass the permissions problem.

But no; any kind of read command gets a permission denied.

I'm using a Mac.

How on Earth is this file unreadable with 777 permissions and `cat` running as the superuser?

Comment: If you have a binary you know (or believe) to be malware, why in the world would you set the executable bit on it?

Comment: Wow, thats incredibly reckless. Why not put the permissions as 600 instead? That way your not accidentally executing the file and killing your computer.

Comment: Wow... that is reckless. Why?

Comment: Include your OS and whether or not you are running SELinux or any kind of security software

Comment: And, you know, _the error you are seeing_ when you try to `cat` the file.  SELinux is unlikely on a Mac (:.

Answer (score 1):

Do not set this file's permissions to 777 if you believe it to be malicious in nature.  You should probably set them to 600 so that only the file's owner can interact with it *but not inadvertantly execute* it.

If you are the owner, you should not need to `sudo cat` it (and indeed if you believe it to be malicious you should not `sudo` *anything* (other than `rm`) it.

Once you own the file and its permissions are 600, you should be able to simply:

```
$ cat file
```

Comment: my whole question is that i get a perms error on something with readable permissions that i own.

Comment: In that case please edit your question to actually ask the actual question, and include the actual error you are seeing.  We can't answer questions you are not actually asking.